# hit from cloudfront but not cached in browser

Tags: .net, iis, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a dotnet web app running in an iis elastic beanstalk container and I have the following in web.config:

```
<clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00.01:00:00"/>
```

When I hit the CF url and check the response headers for an image I see "Hit from cloudfront" with a status code of 304 not modified.

If I take a look in FF or Chrome dev tools I can see that the images are not being cached in the browser.

What am I missing to enable client side caching?

Answer (score 0):

use the correct format:

cacheControlMaxAge="**00:05:00**"